# C# Remote Method Invocation (RMI)

Tags: c#

I need to write an RMI server and client in C# and was sort of confused about what this really is considering most of the posts I have read online on the subject have been Java-related. What exactly is C#'s version of Java RMI? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for [.Net Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You may also want to look into [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

Comment: WCF if it's available. .NET Remoting is, I believe, more philosophically aligned with RMI, but is not recommended for new development.

Comment: @Mark: It's not recommended for new development? Are you sure?

Comment: The WCF link is out of date. Some current replacements are: 

[Migrating from .NET Remoting to WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn874023.aspx)  and  

[Windows Communication Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .net 3.0 or better, look into WCF (Windows Communication Foundation).  If you are using .net 2.0 or older, look at .Net Remoting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use anything except WCF if you want fast and lightweight application without writing tons of xml or hours to configure calculator.

Comment: But WCF is the lightweight alternative to writing tons of XML or hours to configure calculator. I know that because I have a calculator service I wrote and did not have to write a single XML for it.